# libraries alternative to gcc stack-protector / fortity source feature on linux

Tags: hardening, buffer-overflow, c, format-string

is there external library/approach/whatever to add

1. canary protection (stack-protector equivalent)
2. extra buffer boundary check (fortity source equivalent)

on a C software without using glibc / gcc built-in functionality ?

Comment: What requirements do you have that aren't satisfied by the built-in functionality?

Comment: There isn't nothing wrong with the built-in functionality, my constraint is that I can't link the glibc.

Comment: Surely those features aren't reliant on linking a library? I was under the impression that they're features of the compiler rather than features of libc.

Comment: No, compiler add pre/post function check on the code for canary etc, but the functional code for the canary check or fail are in the libc. They are respectively __stack_chk_guard/__stack_chk_fail .

Answer (score 2):

Carnary protections rely on the compiler adding code before and after each function body, and possibly resorting the function's local variables, so this is **not** possible for item 1.

As for item 2, the only thing that does come to mind is running the executable under Valgrind for analysis. You will not want to do that in production, as it's slow. Furthermore, some GCC builtins behave badly under Valgrind (e.g. the `strlen` builtin can read up to 3 bytes (on i386) past the end of an allocated buffer), so this will emit false positives.

I'd say, your *only* way forward is to recompile the application with SSP enabled (also, GCC ships libssp which contains functions to do item 2). Many other C libraries contain SSP supporting code (it's not much code, really) already, so not using the GNU libc is not a problem.

Some other C compilers also contain boundary checks, buffer overflow checks, stack overflow checks, etc. in various states of usability.

You should also look into your `malloc` implementation. Some implementations – most notably omalloc from OpenBSD – offer reserving “guard pages” before and after page-sized allocations, and moving smaller allocations to either the beginning or end of a page, to catch accesses beyond the buffer.